# Email Piping/Processing with Python

Tags: python, pipe

I am in the process of developing a web-based application, for which I need to be able to pipe incoming emails to a specific address (already done) to a python script (already done).  I set up the pipe easily enough, but when I send emails to the target address, I get this response:

```
A message that you sent could not be delivered to one or more of its
recipients. This is a permanent error. The following address(es) failed:

  pipe to |/path/to/script.py
    generated by ****@****.com
    local delivery failed
```

The script appears as follows (and obviously doesn't do anything yet):

```
#!/home2/tsassone/python/bin/python    
def main():    
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I know the paths are all correct, and the hash-bang is used on other, functioning scripts.   All the email needs to do is pull the body/content of the message out and parse it (going to be putting certain parts into a database).  What do I need to do to fix the piping to prevent the error, and how do I access the email body once I have (I understand how to use stdin, and did some reading on email parsing, but none of it worked, though I'm not sure if that's because the pipe was broken, or something else).

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Is the script executable? Does the mail server have sufficient permissions to access and execute it?

Comment: Does running your script by itself work? Your post here seems to lack a body for the main() function. To do nothing, you should use the `pass` statement.

Comment: I believe it has access - it's all on the same host (BlueHost), and I've been able to execute python scripts through forms and links. I'm not certain if the file itself is executable - if I try to run it via SSH I'm told I don't have permission, and sudo didn't work either.  If I run it via the python interpretter, however (python file.py) it works just fine.

Comment: Then that would be a no.